# WordPress Base Page not working?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use a custom display for some civicrm page as error contribution form pages.

So i have created a template wordpress page named civicrm, fill "civicrm" in WordPress Base Page field in admin.

I have inserted the shortcode to insert a contribution form
But when i validate the form on frond end i am not redirected to the good url (the one with base page i have specified)

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error message ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try telling CiviCRM what is your base template.php pasting this in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'civicrm_basepage_template', 'my_basepage_template' ); 

function my_basepage_template( $template ) { 
return 'page.php'; 
}
```

Replace page.php with the page template in use by your theme.

If that doesn't work, try changing to the default WordPress theme (Twenty Fifteen) and try submitting the form in the Contribution page you have created and report back.

Comment: Just to say it'll need to be 4.6 for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It won't actually redirect you to the URL of the WordPress Base Page.  What it will do is append a query string to the URL of the page that had the shortcode, and then it will use the *content* of the WordPress Base Page.

See my answer to my own question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8904/wp-base-page-not-working-as-expected?rq=1) for more details.